# How to override "save_model" for UserAdmin of User model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i'm trying to override save_model when i enter an existing email i get this error
"<User: >" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):


    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
            email = form.data.get("email")
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
                return messages.error(
                    request, _("An account with this email address already exists.")
                )
            else:
                obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data["password"])
                if (
                    Group.objects.get(id=form.data.get("groups")).is_staff
                    and form.data.get("is_staff") is None
                ):
                    obj.is_staff = True
                if (
                    not Group.objects.get(id=form.data.get("groups")).is_staff
                    and form.data.get("is_staff") is not None
                ):
                    obj.is_staff = False
                obj.save()
                EmailAddress.objects.create(email=email,user_id=obj.id)
                return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

i think this error is triggered because it's trying to add user id to groups model but the user is not being created how can i fix it